# gitlab-ci install specific yarn version

Tags: gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

i have trouble with gitlab Continous integration. in localhost it `yarn start` work without problem even unit-test `yarn berry version 2.4.2`

**my `.yarnrc.yml`**

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-2.4.2.cjs
```

how to install a specific version of yarn in gitlab with `gitlab-ci.yml` please ?

I tryed with this different configuration and all failed

**my gitlab-ci.yml**

```
...
unit-tests:
  stage: test
  image: node:15.2.1-alpine3.11
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .yarn/
  script:
    - yarn set version 2.4.2
    /* tested also with
      yarn set version https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/2.4.2@1.0.0/
      yarn set version 2.4.2.cjs
      yarn set version https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/2.4.2
    */
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
    - yarn test
```

**the error**

```
 00:01
Using docker image sha256:7ddc154413f500a1ec545a38fe661bf0fd138e061495e5786ef017352b52c52d for node:15.2.1-alpine3.11 with digest node@sha256:7614f96f47ede63333a7ddbd31c71207956eb39b641e724f81c198c067bacf41 ...
$ yarn set version 2.4.2.cjs
Resolving 2.4.2.cjs to a url...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Release not found: 2.4.2.cjs".
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution : using `yarn set version 2.4.2`alone don't work

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test
  - release

unit-tests:
  stage: test
  image: node:15.2.1-alpine3.11
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .yarn/
  script:
    - yarn set version berry      <--- get last version
    - yarn set version 2.4.2      <--- then downgrade to a specific version
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
    - yarn test
    ...
```

Dockerfile ( for build in CI)

```
...
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn set version berry
RUN yarn set version 2.4.2
RUN yarn install
...
```